# Expression for Omitted Variable Bias in Particular Coefficient

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, omitted-variable-bias

Suppose the true model is $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{1i}+\beta_2x_{2i}+\epsilon_i$, but $x_2$ is not observable.

If we run a regression instead on the model $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{1i}+\eta_{1i}$, what is an expression for the bias in the coefficient $\hat{\beta_1}$ alone?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579428/adjusting-for-confounding-in-linear-regression-model/579481#579481